# Trigger for checking that a user can't add himself as a friend

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table (Usuario) and a nested table inside of it (Amigos), and also a TYPE (AmigosList). These is the structure of those tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Usuario_ObjTyp AS OBJECT (
    id_usuario NUMBER(8),
    nick VARCHAR2(20),
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    apellido VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    contrasena VARCHAR(30),
    ct_amigos NUMBER(4),
    direccion VARCHAR2(30),
    localidad VARCHAR2(20),
    cp VARCHAR2(7),
    pais VARCHAR2(20),
    telefono VARCHAR2(10),
    Tarjetas REF Tarjeta_Credito_ObjTyp,
    PayPal_Usuario REF Paypal_ObjTyp,
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Get_Nick RETURN VARCHAR2
); 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Amigos_ntabtyp IS TABLE OF REF Usuario_ObjTyp;
```

I also have this TYPE for the nested table, for the trigger

```
ALTER TYPE Usuario_ObjTyp ADD ATTRIBUTE AmigosList Amigos_ntabtyp CASCADE;
```

The case is, everytime i want to add a friend to an user, or modify it, it needs to check that that friend isnt the user itself. Also, for example, we have user1 and user2, when user1 makes friend to user2, it needs to check that user1 isn't adding itself, and add to user1,in the AmigosList, the user2, and in the AmigosList list of user2 the user1.

What I try its this (I'm really confused on how to make it):
Notes: -VCA: the number of friends an user has.
-ct_amigos: number of friends an user has.

```
--for the main table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_NoMismoAmigo
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON Usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        VCA NUMBER;
        I BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.AmigosList IS NOT NULL THEN
            VCA := 0;
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.AmigosList.COUNT LOOP
                VCA := VCA + 1;
            END LOOP;
        ELSE
            VCA := 0;
        END IF;

        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO USUARIO_OBJTAB
            VALUES (:NEW.id_usuario, :NEW.nick, :NEW.nombre, :NEW.apellido, :NEW.email, :NEW.contrasena, VCA, :NEW.direccion, :NEW.localidad, :NEW.cp, :NEW.pais, :NEW.telefono, :NEW.tarjetas, :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, :NEW.AmigosList);
        END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE USUARIO_OBJTAB SET id_usuario = :NEW.id_usuario, nick = :NEW.nick, nombre = :NEW.nombre, apellido = :NEW.apellido, email = :NEW.email, contrasena = :NEW.contrasena, ct_amigos = VCA, direccion = :NEW.direccion, localidad = :NEW.localidad, cp = :NEW.cp, pais = :NEW.pais, telefono = :NEW.telefono, Tarjetas = :NEW.tarjetas, Paypal_Usuario = :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, AmigosList = :NEW.AmigosList
            WHERE id_usuario = :OLD.id_usuario;
        END IF;
    END;

--for nested table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_NoMismoAmigo_N
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON NESTED TABLE AmigosList OF Usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF INSERTING THEN
            UPDATE USUARIO_OBJTAB 
                SET ct_amigos = ct_amigos + 1
                WHERE id_usuario != :PARENT.id_usuario;     -- Check if its not the same user?
            INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT AmigosList FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB WHERE id_usuario = :PARENT.id_usuario)
                VALUES (:NEW.COLUMN_VALUE);
        END IF;

        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE USUARIO_OBJTAB
                SET ct_amigos = ct_amigos --if we delete and add another friend it sets the same
                WHERE id_usuario = :PARENT.id_usuario;
            UPDATE TABLE (SELECT AmigosList FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB WHERE id_usuario != :PARENT.id_usuario) 
                SET COLUMN_VALUE = :NEW.COLUMN_VALUE;
        END IF;
    END;
```

The insertion I've tried is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT AmigosList FROM Usuario_ObjTab WHERE id_usuario = 3 ) 
VALUES ((SELECT REF(U) FROM Usuario_ObjTab U WHERE id_usuario = 3));
```

The result i get from the insertion is that it adds to the user itself as a friend (which it's not correct).

Maybe I'm just confused, but I'm stuck in there. Please help me, thank you so much.

--UPDATE
I tried this, still gives me an error of too many values in   INSERT INTO TABLE(SELECT AmigosList FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB u WHERE REF(u)=:new.AmigosList(I)) values (:NEW.id_usuario, :NEW.nick, :NEW.nombre,
:NEW.apellido, :NEW.email, :NEW.contrasena, :NEW.CT_AMIGOS, :NEW.direccion, :NEW.localidad, :NEW.cp, :NEW.pais, :NEW.telefono, :NEW.tarjetas, :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, :NEW.AmigosList);
END LOOP;
But i dont know why. Here is the trigger in the main table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER Act_NoMismoAmigo
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        I BINARY_INTEGER;
        VUSER REF USUARIO_OBJTYP;
    BEGIN
      Select ref(a) into VUSER from usuario_objtab a where id_usuario = :new.id_usuario;
      --if el id del nuevo usuario es distinto al de nuestro usuario: se añade a su AmigosList
        IF :NEW.AmigosList IS NOT NULL THEN
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.AmigosList.COUNT LOOP
                IF :new.AmigosList(I) = VUSER THEN
                   raise_application_error(-20111, 'No se puede añadir, coincide');
                END IF;     
            END LOOP;
           --insert lista/actualizacion
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.AmigosList.COUNT LOOP
                 INSERT INTO TABLE(SELECT AmigosList FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB u WHERE REF(u)=:new.AmigosList(I)) values (:NEW.id_usuario, :NEW.nick, :NEW.nombre, 
                 :NEW.apellido, :NEW.email, :NEW.contrasena, :NEW.CT_AMIGOS, :NEW.direccion, :NEW.localidad, :NEW.cp, :NEW.pais, :NEW.telefono, :NEW.tarjetas, :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, :NEW.AmigosList);
            END LOOP;
           
           
            --actualizacion/borrado lista 
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.AmigosList.COUNT LOOP
                 DELETE FROM TABLE (SELECT AmigosList FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB u WHERE REF(u)=:OLD.AmigosList(I)) WHERE COLUMN_VALUE = VUSER;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: I'm confused, is there a reason to make it that complicated? Why not another (non-nested) table 'Amigos' that holds the id_usuario of the users and friends?

Comment: I don't know, I just can work with that sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little idea. This is untested code, maybe it could help, maybe not.
I adapted your first trigger a bit:

```
--for the main table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_NoMismoAmigo
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON Usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        i BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
    
        IF :NEW.AmigosList IS NOT NULL THEN
            FOR i IN :NEW.AmigosList.FIRST..:NEW.AmigosList.LAST LOOP
                IF :NEW.AmigosList(i).id_usuario = :NEW.id_usuario THEN
                    :NEW.AmigosList.DELETE(i); -- Remove self-reference from list - user can't be friend of itself
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
            
            :NEW.AmigosList := SET (:NEW.AmigosList); -- Make the list distinct
            :NEW.ct_amigos := :NEW.AmigosList.COUNT;
        ELSE
            :NEW.ct_amigos := 0;
        END IF;
    
        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO USUARIO_OBJTAB
            VALUES (:NEW.id_usuario, :NEW.nick, :NEW.nombre, :NEW.apellido, :NEW.email, :NEW.contrasena, :NEW.ct_amigos, :NEW.direccion, :NEW.localidad, :NEW.cp, :NEW.pais, :NEW.telefono, :NEW.tarjetas, :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, :NEW.AmigosList);
        END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE USUARIO_OBJTAB SET id_usuario = :NEW.id_usuario, nick = :NEW.nick, nombre = :NEW.nombre, apellido = :NEW.apellido, email = :NEW.email, contrasena = :NEW.contrasena, ct_amigos = VCA, direccion = :NEW.direccion, localidad = :NEW.localidad, cp = :NEW.cp, pais = :NEW.pais, telefono = :NEW.telefono, Tarjetas = :NEW.tarjetas, Paypal_Usuario = :NEW.PayPal_Usuario, AmigosList = :NEW.AmigosList
            WHERE id_usuario = :OLD.id_usuario;
        END IF;     
    END;
```

Comment: Could you please also help me with the nested-table trigger? Thank you so much

Comment: To be honest, this concept is a brainf**k for me. I've tried to create a minimal useable version of your setup and even trying it makes me angry with every keystroke. ;)  Unfortunatelly i'm not of any help here, i'm really sorry!

Comment: Don't worry, thank you so much for trying.